# boolean method passed through a string to return either true or false

Tags: java, string, boolean

I need to use a boolean to return true or false based on what is in the string. If the list has a "Penny" in it, it's supposed to return false, but I can't seem to get it to do that. Any suggestions or things I'm messing up?

```
public class Purse
{
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Purse c = new Purse();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    c.addCoin("Quarter");
    c.addCoin("Dime");
    c.addCoin("Nickel");
    c.addCoin("Penny");

    System.out.println(c.toString());
}

public void addCoin(String coinName)
{
    list.add(coinName);
}

public boolean findCoin(String coinName)
{

        if(list.contains("Penny"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }

}

public String toString()
{
    return this.getClass().getCanonicalName() + list.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: Java !== JavaScript.

Comment: you're not even calling `findCoin`

Comment: You forgot to tell us what actually is happening, and you also forgot to tell us what it's supposed to look like when it's successful

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to this site. It's supposed to just print the string out, unless there is a penny in the string, where is would just return false and not print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call find method that will decide boolean value you want.

so call it like:

```
if (findCoin("mycoin")) {
   System.out.println(c.toString());
}
```

Also you defined scanner so am assuming you need to read it from user so use it.